# IW parameter not returning start of week and not able to handle logical expression using CASE

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table test(id number,col timestamp(6));
insert into test values(1,TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-11-09 06:14:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
insert into test values(2,TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-11-07 09:14:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

Database: Oracle Live
```

I have a requirement where I need to check with weekdays by comparing the date timestamp column.

1. First I need to check if the `col` (For e.g 09-Nov-2022) lies between Tuesday & Sunday if it does then need to display next Monday date and time(14-Nov-2022 09:14:00.742000000').

2.If the `col` lies on Monday(14-Nov-2022) then need to check time if it is `>8am` then need to display next monday date and time(21-Nov-2022 09:14:00.742000000').

My attempt:

`trunc(col,'IW')` this is not returning the start week of the day i.e Monday but ideally it should return MOnday which is not coming in my attempt.

```
select 
case when trunc(col) between trunc(col,'IW')+1 and trunc(col,'IW')+6 then --need to display next monday date & time
when trunc(col) = trunc(col,'IW') --and time is after 8am 
 then --need to display next monday date & time
from test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You needed "Dy" parameter for checking whether it's monday or not

The "col + to_number(TRUNC(col, 'iw') + 7 - trunc(col))" clause calculates (TRUNC(col, 'iw') + 7 - trunc(col)) and adds number of days to make date to next monday

```
select 
  case 
  when to_char(col, 'Dy') = 'Mon' then
    case
    when col > (trunc(col) + 8/24) then 
      col + 7
    else col end
  else -- since it's not Mon, it lays between Tue and Sun
    col + to_number(TRUNC(col, 'iw') + 7 - trunc(col))
  end
  from test
```

Here's [db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hgP6TSSC) to check

UPD 1. Explanation for the "col + to_number(TRUNC(col, 'iw') + 7 - trunc(col))" statement

- **trunc(col)** - cuts the time off from col's date which equals to  "2022-11-09 00:00:00"
- **TRUNC(col, 'iw') + 7** - sets the date to monday of the next week

So, "to_number(TRUNC(col, 'iw') + 7 - trunc(col))" gives you amount of days you need to add to get next monday

Finally, "col + to_number(TRUNC(col, 'iw') + 7 - trunc(col))" adds number of days to get the monday of the next week and preserve time

UPD 2. As per Wernfried Domscheit comment I had to mention that to_char(col, 'Dy') equals to the 'Mon' only when your NLS settings are set to english. But since you're looking for 'Mon' in the question, your database is set to the right language

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround and providing the optimized solution. However I did not understand the last logic ```col + to_number(TRUNC(col, 'iw') + 7 - trunc(col))```. Is this for getting values in timestamp?

Comment: Result of `to_char(col, 'Dy')` depends on current user session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` setting, better use `to_char(col, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you're right. I assumed the OP is having "english" nls setings since she was looking for Mon in the question. But still I had to mention it in the answer. I'll update it

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the number of days between the value and the start of the week instead of using `between` then it's a bit simpler:

```
case
  when trunc(col) - trunc(col, 'IW') > 0 or extract(hour from col) >= 8
  then col + ((7 - (trunc(col) - trunc(col, 'IW'))) * interval '1' day)
  else col
end
```

If the number of days between today - `trunc(col)` - and the start of the week - `trunc(col, 'IW')` - is greater than zero then the value isn't from Monday; or it is zero but after 08:00:00; then add the appropriate number of days to take to to the following Monday - at the same time, which is what you showed, but seems a little odd.

As a demo with a couple of extra values to cover what you mentioned in the question:

```
select id, col,
  case
    when trunc(col) - trunc(col, 'IW') > 0 or extract(hour from col) >= 8
    then col + ((7 - (trunc(col) - trunc(col, 'IW'))) * interval '1' day)
    else col
  end as adjusted
from test;
```

| ID | COL | ADJUSTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09-NOV-22 06.14.00.742000 | 14-NOV-22 06.14.00.742000000 |
| 2 | 07-NOV-22 09.14.00.742000 | 14-NOV-22 09.14.00.742000000 |
| 3 | 14-NOV-22 07.59.59.999000 | 14-NOV-22 07.59.59.999000000 |
| 4 | 14-NOV-22 08.00.00.000000 | 21-NOV-22 08.00.00.000000000 |
| 5 | 14-NOV-22 08.00.00.001000 | 21-NOV-22 08.00.00.001000000 |
| 6 | 14-NOV-22 09.14.00.742000 | 21-NOV-22 09.14.00.742000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a-ikfVrg)

You said ">8am" and "time is after 8am" but I've assumed you actually meant "8am or later", so I've used `hour >= 8`. If you didn't mean that - so you did really mean that 08:00:00 is not adjusted but 08:00:01 is - then that would again seem odd, but you can check the other time components:

```
select id, col,
  case
    when trunc(col) - trunc(col, 'IW') > 0
      or extract(hour from col) > 8
      or extract(minute from col) > 0
      or extract(second from col) > 0
    then col + ((7 - (trunc(col) - trunc(col, 'IW'))) * interval '1' day)
    else col
  end as adjusted
from test;
```

| ID | COL | ADJUSTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09-NOV-22 06.14.00.742000 | 14-NOV-22 06.14.00.742000000 |
| 2 | 07-NOV-22 09.14.00.742000 | 14-NOV-22 09.14.00.742000000 |
| 3 | 14-NOV-22 07.59.59.999000 | 21-NOV-22 07.59.59.999000000 |
| 4 | 14-NOV-22 08.00.00.000000 | 14-NOV-22 08.00.00.000000000 |
| 5 | 14-NOV-22 08.00.00.001000 | 21-NOV-22 08.00.00.001000000 |
| 6 | 14-NOV-22 09.14.00.742000 | 21-NOV-22 09.14.00.742000000 |